# Can htacess validate a slashed url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL:

```
www.example.com/username/password/4
```

I have a file (`access.txt`) where username & passwords are listed.

```
Example: John:1234
```

I want to validate if the username & password is correct from the URL, if it is correct then redirect the user to a URL.

I can do it with PHP by this kind of URL: `www.example.com/redirect.php?username=username&password=password&id=4`

but is it possible to do it via `.htacess`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually are trying to do here, but in general, passing passwords in the URL (either as a URL segment or as a query parameter) is a bad idea. Anyone can just look at the URL and see the password in clear text. Use POST instead of GET when sending data.

Comment: I'm going to suggest: Go back to the drawing board on this one. Really, what it sounds like you are doing, is just not a good way to go about user/pass in any sense of the word.

Comment: This is just an example dear, Do you know how to change example.com/john/1234 into example.com/user=john&password=1234?

Comment: Does this help? https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^\/]+)&l=([^\/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ search/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^search/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)$ search.php?q=$1&l=$2 [QSA,L]
```